# A limit parametric with Taylor Polynomial

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Is it possible solve the $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin^x(x)-1}{x^\alpha}$$ without Taylor?
Maybe this is solvable only with taylor series (if there is some way without i am very happy to read it). Anyway i would ask if it's possible with Taylor series how can know until order we must expanding if we don't know the value of $\alpha$

Comment: 1. Find a suitable range of $\alpha$ for which the limit exists. 2. Find the limit, probably it depends on $\alpha$.

Comment: thank you @insipidintegrator

Comment: The numerator is $O(x\log(x))$.  So the limit is $0$ when $\alpha<1$ and diverges otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite the limit as $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{e^{x\log(\sin x)}-1}{x^\alpha}$$ and observe that $x\log(\sin x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$, then you can use the well-known limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1$$ to finish this off without Taylor. I'll let you work out the other details to conclude from here.